# Tree-based communication in MPI barrier

Tags: mpi, barrier

This below link describes the barrier implementation in MPI (Message Passing Interface).
[How is barrier implemented in message passing systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626423/how-is-barrier-implemented-in-message-passing-systems)
However, tree-based communication in MPI barrier is not described. What will be the implementation of tree-based communication in MPI barrier?

Answer (score 0):

Since the major implementations OpenMPI and MPICH2 are open source and some commercial flavors are besed on them you could find out for yourself. The guys behind MPICH2 may evene have published papers about their implementation.

The answer may even depend on the actual device (shm, tcp, infiniband) being used.